# AuthenticationException with BloggerService

Tags: blogger, gdata, google-api-java-client

I run my program for several years, doing the same procedure for authentication with Blogger. Yesterday afternoon (May 26, 2015) I started to get AuthenticationException. I have not changed my code... The error happened a few hours after having successfully published my posts into my blog. Did anything happen?
Here is the error:

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:688)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
    at freebies.coffinate.com.FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone.(FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone.java:180)
    at freebies.coffinate.com.FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone.main(FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone.java:1177)

Here is the way I get the permission:

Line 1177 of FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone:

FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone fr = new FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone(new BloggerService("cbh-freebie-1"),                  userName,userPassword,"");

Line 180 of FreediesBatchFeedStandAlone:

myService.setUserCredentials(un, password);

In summary, very straightforward authentication that decided not to work since yesterday afternoon.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`setUserCredentials` uses ClientLogin, which was deprecated and recently disabled. You should use `setOAuth2Credentials` instead. See the [google-oauth-java-client documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2) for how to get a Credential.